# exporting a table widget in excel with headers

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I need exporting a table widget as an excel file including vertical and horizontal headers

This code allows doing that but without the headers:

```
    def createTable(self):
   # Create table
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['a','b'])
    print(self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1).text())
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.move(0,0)

    # table selection change
    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click_table)

def savefile(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)")
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    for currentColumn in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for currentRow in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, currentColumn).text())
            sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, teext)
    wbk.save(filename[0])
```

That's the output:

[image]

How is possible include headers?

Tks

Comment: It's kind of out of topic, but which lib did you use to create the xls file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use the model instead of the items, and the idea is only to move the indexes:

```
def savefile(self):
    filename,_ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)")
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font = xlwt.Font()
    font.bold = True
    style.font = font
    model = self.tableWidget.model()
    for c in range(model.columnCount()):
        text = model.headerData(c, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sheet.write(0, c+1, text, style=style)

    for r in range(model.rowCount()):
        text = model.headerData(r, QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        sheet.write(r+1, 0, text, style=style)

    for c in range(model.columnCount()):
        for r in range(model.rowCount()):
            text = model.data(model.index(r, c))
            sheet.write(r+1, c+1, text)
    wbk.save(filename)
```

Comment: Perfect as usual. I would like deepen my comprehension of model, can you advice me some sources? Tks

Comment: quite tough stuff for me... I still being confused: I have code with two different kind of objects, table view (you advised me to use it this to load in it a pandas DataFrames) and table widget (I learned how to edit them, adding/removing columns and exporting) that have a model as well, as highlighted above. Now, I need implementing tables able to load and save data frames and excel files with flexibility. What can I do? Which object has to be used? Can you support me privately? tsk